# Solving periodic high PAGELATCH_EX Waits. Last page contention?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Really need some help on an issue with `PAGELATCH_EX` waits due to heavy inserts. We see random spikes in `PAGELATCH_EX` and `_SH` on the waits on a simple insert to a table.

Happens just a few times a day but can cause queuing on our web application when there is brief lockup and increase in wait time. The server is way over spec'd and SSD disks don't seem to be anywhere near I/O capacity.

I read `PAGELATCH_EX` was due to the sequential clustered primary key in the table along with last page contention, so I have changed the clustered index to a GUID and changed the original sequential id to a non-clustered index as we still need to query based on this id.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look to have solved the issue. I have also tried to put a 70% fill factor on the indexes. Will the sequential non clustered index still cause `PAGELATCH_EX`? Do we need to put a non-unique number as part of this index as well?

Here is the new table with GUID and all the indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[data_202210](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [sequentialnumber] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [w1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [h1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [datetime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [p1] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [memberid] [bigint] NULL,
    [datatype] [int] NOT NULL,
    [datavalueid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [categoryid] [bigint] NULL,
    [categorytype] [int] NULL,
    [orderid] [bigint] NULL,
    [ordertotal] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
    [url] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,
    [img] [nvarchar](2048) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_data_Id_202210] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[data_202210] ADD  DEFAULT (newid()) FOR [Id]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[data_202210]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CC_data_202210_Id_datetime] CHECK  (([datetime]>='2022-10-01' AND [datetime]<'2022-11-01'))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[data_202210] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CC_data_202210_Id_datetime]
GO

--this is the old clustered index which is sequentially created number in our application
--still used in a queries to join to another table
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [pigdataid_202210] ON [dbo].[data_202210]
(
    [sequentialnumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 70) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- covering indexes for querying the data
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [lookup_202210] ON [dbo].[data_202210]
(
    [w1] ASC,
    [p1] ASC,
    [datetime] ASC,
    [datatype] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [trending_lookup_202210] ON [dbo].[data_202210]
(
    [w1] ASC,
    [datatype] ASC,
    [datetime] ASC
)
INCLUDE ([datavalueid]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 70) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I used various queries to see the waits as well as RedGate SQL Monitor.

Server is 16 CPU and 128GB RAM. Disks are 10,000 IOPS, 500 MB/s throughput. Around 400 inserts per sec at peak. I wouldn't have thought 400 was a lot, but the waits were definitely pointing to `PAGELATCH_EX` and `PAGELATCH_SH`. The insert was taking about 1ms. Other waits were ok.

Unfortunately, we can't move to SQL Server 2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing method 6 with partitions on primary filegroup from [Resolve last-page insert PAGELATCH_EX contention in SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/resolve-pagelatch-ex-contention#method-6-use-table-partitioning-and-a-computed-column-with-a-hash-value) improved our insert total duration performance from 1ms to 0.1ms.

No more spikes in `PAGELATCH_EX` or `_SH`.
Would recommend to anyone running SQL 2016 SP1 or 2017.

> ###### Method 6: Use table partitioning and a computed column with a hash value
>
> Use table partitioning and a computed column that has a hash value to spread out the INSERT operations. Because this method uses table partitioning, it's usable only on Enterprise editions of SQL Server.
>
> ℹ Note
>
> You can use Partitioned tables in SQL Server 2016 SP1 Standard Edition. For more information, see the description of "Table and index partitioning" in the article [Editions and supported features of SQL Server 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2016#RDBMSSP).

Also found [Pros and Cons of Last Page Contention Solutions For SQL Server](https://www.erikdarlingdata.com/pros-and-cons-of-last-page-contention-solutions/) by Erik Darling very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You still have an index on the sequentially increasing key, you just changed it from a clustered index to a non-clustered index. It is still a B-Tree. It is possible that the contention has been reduced, thanks to the new "increasing" index being more narrow, though.

Fillfactor < 100 won't help, since the last page will fill upp immediate. I.e., the fillfactor is only relevant when you create the index. All you achieved by specifying a value < 100 was to make the index bigger.

You want to make sure that your issues are on the increasing index (being a clustered or a non-clustered). The article at the end of this post has a query that allow you to determine that. Just seeing accumulated waits for PAGELATCH_* isn't enough to determine that.

If possible, do a test with SQL Server 2019. It has an index option for this situation: `OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY`. It will change scheduling so that a thread which is more likely to finish within a quanta (4 ms) will get priority in the queue, hence reducing expensive context switching. It will likely not reduce the accumulated wait, but it will likely increase throughput (which is what you want in the end). [See this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-index-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#sequential-keys).

This MS article discusses your problem situation and has a query to determine if this is your actual problem, and possible ways to improve the situation; including the index option mentioned above. There's not much you can do if you still require an index on the sequential value and if this index is where the contention is, except for the above index option, but again it requires SQL Server 2019. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/resolve-pagelatch-ex-contention